# Get Url page that contains a specific component with C#

Tags: content-delivery, 2009

In a dll in C# I get the tcm of a component. This component is placed in the metadata of a strucure group.

What I need is to get the url of the page that is using this component.
Ultimately what I need to do in C# is the same that Tridion does when you write `tridion:href@@component@@`

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. What you tried so far? Are you referring to C# or Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty simple:

If you don't need to include Template Priorities in your logic (doesn't look like you do):

```cs
ComponentLink link = new ComponentLink(publicationId);
string url = link.GetLink(componentId).Url;
```

If you do need to take template priorities into account:

```cs
ComponentLink link = new ComponentLink(publicationId);
string url = link.GetLink(currentPageId, componentId, componentTemplateToExclude, linkTagAttributes, linkText, textOnFail, showAnchor).Url;
```

Comment: Thanks Nuno,

It was very helpful your answer. I fixed my problem.

Thanks again.